# How to Change a Gridview Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, controls

I have a C# ASP.NET project with a gridview. The gridview has a dataset as a datasource.

The grid includes a date field, but when you edit that field, you have to type in the date, and can't select a date since its a textbox.

How will you go about changing the control of a gridview.

This is what I've tried but it didn't work. (Just tried to convert all the textboxes to a calender as a test.

```
foreach (TableCell cell in grdViewDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells)
{
   cell.Controls[0] = cell.Controls[0] as Calendar; //This didnt work....
   //do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing that u can simply use calender exterder of ajax tool kit.here is the lnik for more details.[Link](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)

Comment: Great link. Will post my solution after I figured out how to implement that extender

Comment: @Ruan welcome...always..its very easy....nothing complex hope you can implement in first attempt

Answer (score 0):

change the date column to template fiels. In edit template add a calender extender to the textbox. Simple.

Comment: Yes, and how will you change the date column to template fields? (Since I cant even change them to a any other control type)